How do I send data between 2 windows PCs?
I'm working on a project where 2 databases are identical in 2 locations away from each other
I have some logic set up to sync them on an interval but now I'm stuck on the communication part
A little context
I live in Egypt and my ISP is We Egypt
I wanted to do this using SSH at the start but after trying I found out that I'm not gonna be able to do that, for some context Why can’t I connect to an SSH server on Windows?
Now what other options do I have to send data from a Windows 11 PC to another without having to rent a server

can the two servers route to each other?

Once you established a SSH connection you can send a file through the same connection.

I can't establish an SSH connection because my ISP won't allow me to be an SSH server and my public IP changes each time the router restarts

Sub-optimal, but may be the only workable way to do it: At intervals, upload from computer-A to a filesharing service like DropBox, and download from DropBox to computer-B at intervals will guarantee non-conflict (i.e., both computers trying to access the dropbox at the same time).

Any software to connect to the machine will require a dns or ip address to connect to the machine.  The simplest method is have a system that both system can access.  You can then transfer the file on one system and download it on another.

If I can have a public IP address that doesn't change for both devices would there be some options other than using something in the middle between the PCs

Provided you're not behind CGNAT, you'd need a DDNS for each server's router when the routers don't have a static public WAN IP from the ISP. Once that's done, you can bypass an ISP port blocking by using higher port numbers for the SSH or router/server based VPN server, such as port numbers in the 50000's. SyncThing can be used to keep files in sync across multiple machines/devices

Well - practically, a VPN might be a solution here. Considering you're essentially running things point to point, something like zerotier or tailscale would handle the 'point to point' connections needed, and they run the connection brokering servers even on their free tier.
Its probably good enough for testing. If not for "not rent a server" I'd say run a VPN yourself.
For file level syncing, there's a load of cloud file sync apps that might help, assuming you want to share data as whole files and not a stream. I was running resilio sync for a bit, though these days I went with a different approach

i have no experience in this VPN idea but I have used Tailscale a couple of times before, is there some tutorial you would suggest to get me started
BTW my goal at the end will be sending some rows from one machine A to B so that machine B will insert these rows into some table and then the other way around

Essentially tailscale should add a virtual adaptor with a local IP on either end. That IP should allow you to SSH from one PC to another as if the two machines are on one lan

This worked perfectly, thanks a lot

I was also looking at the pricing of tailscale and it seems like i won't need more than the personal pack as all i'm doing is connecting 2 PCs together even when i finally deploy
